# Highcharts sparse data - hide empty values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have data that can be very sparse - that is many values are zero.

In this case I'm not so much interested in the zeroes but more the values that actually have a value so I was wondering if there was a way to not display columns which are empty.

Example fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HUBhj/

Think a case like this which is even more sparse with even more columns per category.

I have tried to read the docs as good as I can but I may have missed something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, it  is not possible to simply omit empty values. Your best bet in this case is to [pre-process the results](http://highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use) as described in the documentation.

Comment: hmm, I feared it may be like that. But how do you suggest i pre-process the data - what would that achieve?